# Can VS2010 project targeted to .NET 3.5 be released to .NET 4.0 only machine

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, runtime, release-mode

I am tasked with requirements for the production machine (Server 2008 R2), and am wondering if this project setup would work with only .NET 4.0 installed and IIS 7 for WCF Service. Is .NET 3.5 needed to load assemblies that that are targeted to it?

A VS2010 solution contains several projects:

Projects targeted to .NET 3.5:

- Model (DTO) classes
- Business Logic Layer
- Data Access Layer
- Interfaces for BLL and DAL

Projects targeted to .NET 4.0:

- WCF Service project wrapping BLL methods

In development, there's 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0 installed on the machine and everything works fine with WCF hosted in IIS6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs in to the same issue:

.NET 3.5 isn't required as the released DLLs run just fine with only .NET2 and .NET4 installed.

WCF Service targeted to .NET4 runs OK under IIS 7.0 with no modification or special configuration.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Server 2008 R2 comes with .Net Framework v2.0.50727 installed but you can install the .NET 3.5 Sp1 using: `Server Manager -> Features -> .Net Framework 3.5.1 Features`. I think .NET 4.0 Client is not enough to run your BLL if it's compiled with .NET 3.5

Comment: Stefan - that was my concern as well, but just tried it on a test machine and everything seems to work without .NET 3.5 installed.